# How to make ktor reload JS changes at runtime

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I'm using the KTOR multiplatform project template in IntelliJ (New Project -> Kotlin -> JS Client and JVM Server). Is there any way, when running the project in IntelliJ, to pick up runtime changes to the JS build? When I look at the classpath of the running JVM I don't see where the JS files are being picked up from at all.

Answer (score 1):

Autoreloading is described here:

https://ktor.io/servers/autoreload.html

For Kotlin files compiling to Javascript, though, this does not work properly as one expects, which I presume it is why you posted this question on SO.

I posted a solution that worked for me here

https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/webpack-watch-in-ktor-js-project/18428/4